# Expected value of a function of normal random variable

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, st.statistics

Suppose $X\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$, find the expectation $\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{(1+X^2)^a}\right]$ where $a$ is a fixed positive real number.

Is there an explicit formula for the above expectation?

Comment: If you use $(1+x^2)^{-a}=\sum_{n\geq 0} (-1)^n \binom{n+a-1}a x^{2n}$ and then take moments, it seems like you get a wildly oscillating series. And yet your expectations appear to be real numbers that converge to $0$ as $a$ grows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Mathematica, the expectation is
$$\frac{\Gamma \left(a-\frac{1}{2}\right) \, _1F_1\left(\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{2}-a;\frac{1}{2 \sigma^2}\right)}{\sqrt{2} \sigma
   \Gamma (a)}+\frac{2^{-a} \sigma^{-2 a} \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2}-a\right) \, _1F_1\left(a;a+\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{2
   \sigma^2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi }}.$$